# Use bluetooth on android app only with mac address and password

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth board in an electronic device which I know the mac address and password. I want to develop an android application to connect and transfer data.  Is it possible?  Any sample code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure - There is sample code in the [android bluetooth page.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html)

Comment: I think I was quite specific and I had followed the documentation without success. I will not connect between two Android devices